# Styling bottom buttons android

Tags: android, button

I have two buttons in bottom of screen, but how can I style stock buttons to style of my concept:

[image: my concept]

Here my code layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="180sp"
        android:text="Далее"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Пропустить"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
    </Button>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Добро пожаловать!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
        android:phoneNumber="false"
        android:textSize="33sp"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple ways to do this when building an android application.

The first and simplest is to set your background to an image. To do this add a image to your drawable folders in the res folder, add the correct size images to each drawable folder to correct display across multiple platforms. Once you have imported your image simply put the following line in the layout xml for your button

```
android:background = "@drawable/imported_image"
```

The second is to create an selector android XML file. This will let you set the background image for different states of the buttons. I usually create a file under my res folder in my project called drawable and put the xml file there. The selector file would look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/large_button_on" />  

<item android:drawable="@drawable/large_button_off" />

</selector>
```

the code to put in your Layout xml inside your button should be

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
```

The final way without using any images is to define a shape android xml file for the button. This will instruct how you want the button to be drawn on screen. This xml should be placed in your project the same way we did with the other.

```
  ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:shape="rectangle">

  <gradient android:startColor="#000000" 
    android:endColor="#0000ff"
    android:angle="270" />

  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffff" />

</shape>
```

again if you use this method put the following in your layout xml for your button

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
```

Hope these methods of styling help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an drawable xml file like this and have a different drawable for the different states of you  button

res/drawable/my_button_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
</selector>
```

Then in your button's declaration add the line:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_button_drawable"  />
```

[Android Developer Buttons](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)